# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when loading NSArray from .plist

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, plist, exc-bad-access

I have a plist written from a NSMutableArray by [NSMutableArray writeToFile]. When trying to load that same plist with the following code:

```
NSArray *testArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[self pathForDataFile:@"reportingSpeicher.plist"]];
NSLog(@"count = %@",[testArray count]);
```

I get bad access on the count or on any other operation I try on testArray. BUT:

```
NSLog(@"testArray = %@", testArray);
```

correctly returns:

```
testArray = (
        {
        benutzername = "t.h";
        datum = "2010-07-15";
        dauerInStunden = 1;
        phasenName = "Projektsteuerung,32";
        projektName = "projekt AG,23";
        soapSpeicher =         {
            PasswortAsMD5 = someMD5sum;
            benutzername = "t.h";
            datum = "2010-07-15";
            dauerInStunden = 1;
            phasenid = 32;
            projektid = 23;
            taetigkeit = whateveryoudid;
        };
        taetigkeit = whateveryoudid;
    } )
```

I'm guessing there is either some basic memory management involved or the type returned is somehow corrupted/not an NSArray. Those three lines should really be simple enough - I just can't get it to work. I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialise the array first. Use `NSArray *testArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self pathForDataFile:@"reportingSpeicher.plist"]];`.

Answer (score 0):

Your NSLog statement is incorrect. The %@ format string is used when printing out an Objective-C object, but [testArray count] returns a plain int, and when NSLog tries to send the result a `-description` message to print it out, that results in a crash.  You'll want to use %d instead to print out the integer value.

```
NSLog(@"count = %d",[testArray count]);
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, you're completely right - though it didn't solve the problem, the NSLog was indeed incorrect